# Cauchy's divergence criterion.

Tags: analysis

I need to prove divergence of 
$$x_n = \left(1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)^n$$
with Cauchy's divergence criterion

Comment: And what have you tried then?

Comment: I took n = 2n, m = 2n+1 and receive |(1 + 1/(2n))^2n - (1-1/(2n+1))^(2n-1))|.

Comment: What is Cauchy's divergence criterion, according to you or your textbook?

Comment: (ex)eps > 0 (any) N (ex)n, m >= N: |x_n-x_m|>=eps

Comment: So the quantifiers you write in your first comment are not consistent with that...$\exists \varepsilon>0, \forall N, \exists m\geq n\geq N\text{ s.t. } \ \lvert x_m-x_n\rvert >\varepsilon$.

Comment: I can take any n and m if |x_n-x_m|>=eps. I took n = 2k and m = 2k+1.        Yes, i make a mistake, i mean k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Recall that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1 + \frac {x}{n}\right)^n=e^x.$$
Now convergence to infinity once via even $n$'s and once with odd $n$'s